# Processing White Screen?

Tags: java, arduino, processing, arduino-uno

I'm new to using Arduino and I am trying to replicate [this guide](http://ioblocks.blogspot.com/2014/05/build-simple-transistor-curve-tracer.html).

I got my Arduino wired correctly with the code uploaded to the Arduino. I downloaded processing and updated my Java and tried running the provided code github.com/DaveAppleton/ProcessingCurveTracer.

Although when I run it, I get something that looks like below, just a blank white screen and will not graph anything?

Any suggestions? In the console it shows that it is working.image here:

[image: sketch screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your code as an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the few visible lines of the Console output it looks you are connecting to the right port and getting data, but the data received isn't in the expected format:

> there were 3values
>   0.0,4.71,5.00

and the Processing code is expecting [4 values](https://github.com/DaveAppleton/ProcessingCurveTracer/blob/master/CurveTracer.pde#L120), not 3.
There are two arduino sketches:

- curveTracingNo2.ino sends 3 values
- curveTracingAuto.ino sends 4 values

You can try to use curveTracingAuto.ino if that serves your purposes.

The strange thing is, the Processing code is expecting 4 values, but uses only 3 of them (from `stArr`). Perhaps the Processing code is slightly outdated and the length condition for `stArr` should be for 4 values like so:

```
if (stArr.length != 3) {
```

I'd try this first.